Capacitors only take DC current
I have some doubts regarding capacitor and how it behaves under different conditions.
Case 1
Consider this case where a parallel combination of a capacitor and resistor are receiving a current which is composed of a DC component I_DC along with a peak-to-peak AC ripple of I_AC at a frequency of 1/Ts.

In this case, the DC component of the current of i_in(t) will see only a resistor as the capacitor will appear as a open circuit. The AC component of the current will be divided between the impedance of the capacitor and the impedance of the resistor.
This makes perfect sense.
Case 2
I have now removed the resistor.

Where does the DC component of the current go now?
I know from simulation and from the fundamental capacitor equation of I = Cdv/dt that the capacitor voltage will increase to infinity. But thinking from a impedance and frequency perspective, how can the capacitor now take a DC current, it should appear as an infinite impedance to DC
My answer to this would be that in case 2, there is no steady-state or DC solution to this circuit as the ideal current source can continue to charge the cap voltage beyond the supply. For a real current source, it would stop. Is that a right answer?

You must define the supply. Is it a current source or voltage source? Is it an ideal circuit for simplifying things?

My bad, it is a voltage source rail, 5V for example. Yes it is all ideal

Yes, in case 2 the voltage on the cap will 'stop' somewhere lower than VDD if a PMOS current mirror is used to supply the current.

For an ideal current source and an ideal capacitor, there is indeed no DC steady state.
But in practice the source impedance is finite, and the capacitor will have some leakage resistance in parallel. So the voltage will be limited by that.
And eventually the capacitor's dielectric will break down, at which point the parallel resistance becomes very low again.

But OP just confirmed it was an ideal voltage supply, not current.

@Justme To clarify, the voltage rail ('horinzontal') line is the supply voltage which can be considered ideal. The current source can also be considered ideal.

@AlfroJang80 I asked if the source is a current or voltage source. You said it is a voltage source. The source can't be both simultaneously, unless you define it so.

Case 2 is easier to analyse than case 1, as there are fewer components.
How can the capacitor take a DC current?
The current simply charges the capacitor. If the current continues indefinitely, the voltage will increase to infinity. The graph you have drawn is not correct, it should show an increase of voltage from the first AC cycle to the next, due to the DC component of the current.
That's what 'an infinite impedance to DC' means. Impedance is volts/current. Voltage goes to infinity, so impedance is infinity.
Of course in the real world, the voltage does not increase to infinity, and you could elaborate the circuit diagram to show the components that prevent that, perhaps a voltage limit across the current source. But, for the ideal components you have shown in that simple circuit, the capacitor voltage will go to infinity.
The current continues to flow, a current of I=dQ/dt, or CdV/dt, despite only the capacitor providing a path to ground. Another way to state exactly the same relation is that the capacitor voltage increases at a rate given by dV/dt = I/C.

The graph is for current, not voltage

@AlfroJang80 You're right, it's a graph of current versus time. A graph of voltage against time would be more interesting and informative. A graph of current, from a current source, will read exactly what the current source is outputting, regardless of the load it feeds into. With that unipolar current output, the voltage on the capacitor will increase monotonically.
